# How to call rustfmt in manually generated code?

Tags: rust

So I am generating bindings for a library and on top of that I'm generating most of the safe wrappers for that library.

The way I'm doing is simply generating a String with all the contents and writing to the file with the `File` trait...

I know the bindings crate supports formatting the generated code, but this particular one is not generated by it. Is there a way to make the `build.rs` call rustfmt on that generated file?

Comment: Sure, `build.rs` is a Rust program, so it can certainly call `rustfmt` on any file. Have you tried just doing that? Did it work? If not, what went wrong? I currently don't fully understand what exactly your problem is.

Comment: Ohh... checking the code from Bindgen I see that it is exactly what it does. I thought there was some way to call it like a library or something. Thanks

Comment: Using rustfmt as a library is possible, though I won't  recommend it if you just want to format a file. You need to use the latest nightly to build it, and it will add many dependencies (you are essentially building a parser for the rustc + more).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that rust bindgen uses a regular command call. I thought it was doing through some kind of rustfmt library.
Reference: https://docs.rs/bindgen/0.51.1/src/bindgen/lib.rs.html#1945